# R dplyr filter() object not found

Tags: r, dplyr

After importing a .csv file,

```
library(dplyr)
wages_DataFrame <- read.csv("~/Documents/Econometrics/PS2 data/Ch04.Ex5.HeightWagesUKData/heightwage_british_males.csv")
```

I want to exclude males who are shorter than 40 inches and earn more than 400 pounds, but when I run

```
filter(wages_DataFrame, height33 >= 40 & gwage33 <= 400)
```

R complains that the object `height33` (one of the columns) is not found.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, in order to find help here, please consider [how to write a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038), thank you.

Comment: Well, have you checked that `height33` is a valid column in `wages_DataFrame`? `colnames(wages_DataFrame)` will hold the answer.

Comment: Post the View or Head output